Streamlit slider will refresh the whole page and go to the top
st.subheader('Bernoulli Distribution')

p = st.slider('Probability of Success (p)', 0.0, 1.0, 0.5)

x = [0, 1]
y = [1 - p, p]

fig = figure(title='Bernoulli Distribution', x_axis_label='Outcome', y_axis_label='Probability')
fig.vbar(x=x, top=y, width=0.5)
st.bokeh_chart(fig, use_container_width=True)

I use python module streamlit to build a web about univariate distributions. I want the user can select different values to see the effect. But the problem now is that, when I use st.slider to choose value, the whole page will refresh and the view will go to the top.
Any solutions here?

That's how streamlit works, the page reloads after each interaction with the slider.
A quick fix would be to use Session State :
if "p" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state["p"] = 0.5

st.subheader("Bernoulli Distribution")

p = st.slider("Probability of Success (p)", 0.0, 1.0, 0.5, key="p")

# rest of the code ...

Alternatively, since you're using bokeh, you could use a Slider with components (inspired by @Marc's answer), which seems to be smoother (see full code) :


componets method is okay here, thanks

I really appreciate the code that Timeless provided, it runs smoothly. Based on that idea, I tried to use a slider component outside of Bokeh to change the data. I implemented it through JavaScript, but since Streamlit’s slider doesn’t provide a sliding event, I wasn't sure how to achieve this. In the end, I used SimpleStart to implement it.
If anyone has suggestions or alternative methods, I would love to hear them!
import simplestart as ss
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CustomJS, Slider
from bokeh.resources import CDN
from bokeh.embed import file_html, components

### ui
ss.write('# Bernoulli Distribution Visualization')


def plot(p=0.5):
    x = [0, 1]
    y = [1 - p, p]

    colors = ['#1f77b4', '#ff7f0e']
    source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y, color=colors))
    source.name = "mysource"

    fig = figure(
        title="Bernoulli Distribution",
        x_axis_label="Outcome",
        y_axis_label="Probability",
    )

    fig.title.align = "center"

    fig.vbar(x="x", top="y", width=0.5, color="color", source=source)

    return file_html(fig, CDN, "Bernoulli Distribution")

ss.htmlview(plot())

def change_value(value):
    js = f'''
        const iframe = document.getElementById('myIframe');

        const innerWindow = iframe.contentWindow;

        const bokehDoc = iframe.contentWindow.Bokeh.documents[0];
        const source = bokehDoc.get_model_by_name("mysource"); 
        //console.log("source", source)

        // updata source data
        var value = {value};
        source.data['y'] = [1 - value, parseFloat(value)];
        source.change.emit();
    '''
    return js


def slider_change(event):
    ss.exec_js(change_value(event.value))
    
ss.slider('Probability of Success \(p\)', 0.0, 1.0, 0.5, onchange=slider_change, triggerOnUpdate = True)

the screenshot
online demo

In Streamlit >= 1.33.0, st.experimental_fragments have been introduced and they solve the problem of reload of the entire page:

st.experimental_fragment
Decorator to turn a function into a fragment which can rerun
independently of the full script.
When a user interacts with an input widget created by a fragment,
Streamlit only reruns the fragment instead of the full script.
Source: the Streamlit docs.

With this, you can create this comparison by having the same 2 sliders and graphs being displayed, one inside a fragment, the other without a fragment.
import random

import streamlit as st
from bokeh.plotting import figure

st.subheader(f"Bernoulli Distribution {random.randint(1, 100)}")


def exp_without_fragment():
    st.markdown("### Exp 1 (without fragments)")
    p = st.slider("Probability of Success (p)", 0.0, 1.0, 0.5, key="slider1")

    x = [0, 1]
    y = [1 - p, p]

    fig = figure(
        title="Bernoulli Distribution",
        x_axis_label="Outcome",
        y_axis_label="Probability",
    )
    fig.vbar(x=x, top=y, width=0.5)
    st.bokeh_chart(fig, use_container_width=True)


@st.experimental_fragment
def exp_with_fragment():
    st.markdown("### Exp 2 (with fragments)")
    p = st.slider("Probability of Success (p)", 0.0, 1.0, 0.5, key="slider2")

    x = [0, 1]
    y = [1 - p, p]

    fig = figure(
        title="Bernoulli Distribution",
        x_axis_label="Outcome",
        y_axis_label="Probability",
    )
    fig.vbar(x=x, top=y, width=0.5)
    st.bokeh_chart(fig, use_container_width=True)


exp_without_fragment()

exp_with_fragment()


Notice the random.randint inside the first header. That way, you can see that if the whole page has rerun or not based on whether or not the value changed. You can see that by interacting with the slider inside the fragment, only the fragment is rerun.
Still, for an unknown (to me) reason, when interacting with the slider inside the fragment makes the page still go up. However, as you can see, it does not reload the page.
